# How do I create a table() out of a tibble() in R?

Tags: r

###### Data:

```
df <- data.frame(

  Volume = c("High", "High", "Low", "Low"),

  Race = c("B", "Non-B", "B", "Non-B"),

  Count = c(62, 1366, 10, 97)

) %>% as.tibble()
```

I want to create a table() [contingency table] using the data I have to perform a chi-squared test.

I can't figure it out though.

Comment: `as.tibble()` was deprecated in tibble 2.0.0.
ℹ Please use `as_tibble()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

contingency.table <- df %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = Volume, values_from = Count) %>% 
    column_to_rownames("Race")
```

That creates the 2-by-2 contingency table that you want (with column- and row-name labels):

> High Low 
> B            62        10 
> Non-B  1366     97

Then you can run `chisq.test()` on the table for a chi-squared test:

```r
chisq.test(contingency.table)
```

> Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction
>
> data:   . 
> X-squared = 4.5, df = 1, p-value = 0.03

Answer (score 0):

In the days of yore when statisticians ruled the probabilistic universe, one would not load the entire flippin tidyverse to do a crosstabs and chi-square test, but just use ordinary R functions:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Volume = c("High", "High", "Low", "Low"),
  Race = c("B", "Non-B", "B", "Non-B"),
  Count = c(62, 1366, 10, 97) ) 
( xt <- xtabs( Count ~ Race+Volume, data=df ))
###---
       Volume
Race    High  Low
  B       62   10
  Non-B 1366   97

 chisq.test(xt)
#-----------------
    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  xt
X-squared = 4.5124, df = 1, p-value = 0.03365
```

Comparing the tidyverse output to the base-R output I judge base-R to have better labeling of the columns